# What is the right way to use the services in Vue js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a class with data mapping (MappingService), I just import it into component wrapper and use its methods to convert data.

for example, this is my service class:

```
class WfmMappingService {

    constructor(
        private shiftService: WfmShiftService,
    ) {
    }

    public static demandsMapping(demands: WfmDemandResponseModel): object {}

    public static recommendationsMapping(
        recommendationsResp: WfmRecommendedResponseModel,
        demands: object,
        quantityDays,
    ) {}

    public static employeesMapping(employees: Array<WfmEmployeesResponseModel>): object {}

    public static availablePlansMapping(availablePlans): {[key: string]: WfmAvailablePlan} {}

    getSortRolesIdsList(rolesList: WfmRoleResponseModel[]) {}

    private static getEmptyRecommendedRole(quantityDays, demands?): object {}

    getEmptyPlanEmployee(quantityDays, month, idEmployee, idDayRole, holidays): object {}
}

export { WfmMappingService }
```

and this is my wrapper component

```
    import { WfmMappingService } from '@/services/MappingService';
    const sharedModule = namespace(SHARED_MODULE);

    @Component({})
    export default class wfmPlan extends Vue {
        @Inject(DependencyConstants.WORKSPACESERVICE) private apiService!: WorkspaceService;
        public async getAvailablePlans() {
            const availablePlansResponse: WfmAvailablePlansResponse = await this.apiService.getAvailablePlans();
            const { availablePlans } = availablePlansResponse;
            const availablePlansMapping = WfmMappingService.availablePlansMapping(availablePlans);
            this.$store.dispatch('setAvailablePlans', availablePlansMapping);
        }
```

I really don't understand what is the right way to do it? May be i should make define variable = new WfmMappingService? But my example is working...